# How to solve for the parameters of the Gamma distribution given x for the 50th and 90th percentiles?

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation, gamma-distribution

How can I solve for the parameters alpha and beta given that x = 20 is the 50th percentile, and x = 300 is the 90th percentile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use the notation of the [wikipedia article on the gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Related_distributions) throughout.

Given that there's no simple closed form for the median of a gamma distribution, you'll want to do this numerically.

You can be smart about this, though.  First, note that the ratio of the 90th to 50th percentiles of a gamma distribution depends only on the shape parameter $k$, not the scale parameter $\theta$.  So we can ask: what is the shape parameter $k$ for which the 90th percentile divided by the 50th percentile is $300/20 = 15$?  This is a couple lines in R:

```
f = function(k){qgamma(.9, k, 1)/qgamma(.5, k, 1)}
k0 = uniroot(function(k){f(k)-15}, c(0.1, 1))$root
```

The first line defines a function `f` which returns the 90th percentile of the $gamma(x,1)$ distribution divided by its 50th percentile.    The second line finds a root of $f(x) - 15$ in the interval $[0.1, 1]$ and assigns it to `k0`.

This returns the root $\theta \approx  0.2672395$.

Now the median of a $Gamma(k_0, 1)$ random variable is given by `qgamma(.5, k0, 1)` in R and is equal to $m_0 = 0.05319006$.  So to get the median equal to 20, you need a scale parameter $\theta_0 = 20/m_0 \approx 376.0101$.